# How to kill all current client connections from ServiceHost?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service running in my server, and a couple of clients who consume the service after authenticating themselves against a custom UserNamePasswordValidator, just like the one described in http://burcakcakiroglu.com/?p=2179

The service is implemented with the following properties:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

The server host is instantiated as follows:

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(AsistenciaService));
host.Open();
```

Currently, after a client authenticates the first time, he never has to authenticate again (except after closing the client application).

In the server process, I would like to -kill- all client connections, so they have to authenticate again before consuming the services. Is this possible?

EDIT: The WCF service is hosted in the IIS server.

Comment: Your hosting it as a singleton, so why not simply use `host.Close();`?

Comment: That would work Tim, but I want the service to stay open for new incomming connections (I need to kick out all current users, but allow for new users to connect).

Comment: Not sure what you're end goal is - are you wanting the clients to have to provide some sort of authentication on every call in addition to connecting?  Or do you want to boot them after some period of time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue is authentication. To accomplish that you could use    `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]` on your service implementation and  `[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]` on your service interface. That way, a new `InstanceContext` (and therefore service object) is created for each new client session and maintained for the lifetime of that session (this requires a binding that supports sessions). More details in [this code project article section](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and#Instance%20mode%20=%20per%20session%20and%20Concurrency%20=%20Multiple).

With `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` the life time of service object is independent of the life time of client channels, so  this will create a new service object whenever a new communication session is established and disposed after that. Each client channel gets a dedicated service instance and the subsequent calls in the same session are handled by the same Service object. This is the default value for instancing context. And this will work with all bindings except `basicHttpBinding`.

Your service (at this moment) is a singleton, it lives forever, *and is only disposed of once the host shuts down* and *created exactly once when the host is created*.
Using a singleton does not require clients to maintain a session with the singleton instance, or to use a binding that supports transport-level session. [If the contract that the client consumes has a session, by closing the proxy the client will only terminate the session, not the singleton instance. In addition, the session will never expire.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx)